# Shopify - how to extend a checkout page in app?

Tags: shopify

I would like to create a Shopify app that adds an additional section to the checkout page - a possibility to select the delivery time window. I know that such apps already exist but I want to use my own application server to generate the values that can be selected.

What is the best way to approach this? I've spent last 2 days browsing shopify documentation and following various tutorials but I'm still confused. I thought that application bridge would be the way to go but after playing with it a bit it seems that it only allows to embed application frame in the admin panel, not on the checkout page.

Should my app send a script tag that would call my server and add the whole slot selection UI in javascript? Or should I maybe modify the templates somehow? Can I even make AJAX requests to third party servers from templates?

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Shopify revealed that there will be a Checkout Apps support soon, but that time isn't now.

So at the moment the Checkout page is standalone and you can't use the ScriptTag API in it.

If you are on a Shopify Plus account and you contacted Shopify to allow you to modify the checkout.liquid file you will be able to add your section manually.

With some additional JS logic you can pass the delivery time to the cart.attributes so that it will be present in the order info. But that's pretty much what you can do and only if you have a PLUS account.

If you plan to make larger modifications you will have to create an App that will have a custom checkout process... which will be a huge overkill for adding a single section, but that's a solution as well.

Comment: Thank you. Is checkout page somehow special? How about a cart page? I would like to achieve something similar to https://apps.shopify.com/click-and-collect - I don't think it needs PLUS account

Comment: @PawełChorążyk Checkout is special since that page handles the transactions, so you don't have normal access to it. The cart page is not special you can do whatever you like there since it's part of the theme files and you can modify it without the need of a PLUS account. As for the app I haven't used it so I can't say nothing on that matter.